# udp packet is not received in QThread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, sockets, qthread

I'm trying to receive some packets using a `udpReceiver` class that I have written using `qUdpSocket` in a separate `QThread` :

```
class udpThread : public QThread
{
private:
    QObject * parent;
public:
    udpThread(QObject * parent = 0)
    {
        this->parent = parent;
    }

    void run()
    {
        UdpReceiver * test = new UdpReceiver(parent);
    }
};


class UdpReceiver : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QUdpSocket * S;
    int port;
public:
    UdpReceiver(QObject* parent = 0) : QObject(parent)
    {
        port = 9003;
        initialize();
    }
    UdpReceiver(int p,QObject* parent = 0) : QObject(parent)
    {
        port = p;
        initialize();
    }

    void initialize()
    {
        S = new QUdpSocket();
        S->bind(port);
        S->connect(S,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(readPendingDiagrams()));
        qDebug() << "Waiting for UDP data from port " << port << " ... \n";
    }

public slots:
    void readPendingDiagrams()
    {
        while(S->waitForReadyRead())
        {
            QByteArray datagram;
            datagram.resize(S->pendingDatagramSize());
            QHostAddress sender;
            quint16 senderPort;

            S->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(),&sender, &senderPort);
            qDebug() << datagram.size() << " bytes received .... \n";
            qDebug() << " bytes received .... \n";
        }
    }
};
```

And here is the `main()` method :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);



//    UdpReceiver * net = new UdpReceiver();      

    MainWindow w;

    udpThread * ut = new udpThread();
    ut->start();

    w.show();


    return a.exec();
}
```

Now when I use the `udpReceiver` class to get the packets without the `QThread` it works just fine, but when I use the `udpThread` class it doesn't get the packets or at least the `raedyread()` signal does not activate some how. 
When I try to get the packets without the `QThread` my GUI crashes somehow and the whole program hangs, that's why I want to use `QThread`.
I appreciate if you could help me solve this :)
Regards,

Comment: Did you leave out some code in your `run()` function. All you do is create your `UdpReceiver` and then exit the running thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've fallen into the same trap as many do when working with threads in Qt: http://blog.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/.
It is *almost* always a bad idea to subclass QThread (see http://woboq.com/blog/qthread-you-were-not-doing-so-wrong.html for counterexamples).

Change your code as follows to do it the "intended" way (create a new `QThread` and call `moveToThread` on your `QObject` to move it to the new thread). You'll see from the output that the thread the `UdpReceiver` is created on is not the same as the one it receives data on, which is what you want:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>
#include <QUdpSocket>

class UdpReceiver : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QUdpSocket * S;
    int port;
public:
    UdpReceiver(QObject* parent = 0) : QObject(parent)
    {
        qDebug() << "Construction thread:" << QThread::currentThreadId();

        port = 9003;
        initialize();
    }
    UdpReceiver(int p,QObject* parent = 0) : QObject(parent)
    {
        port = p;
        initialize();
    }

    void initialize()
    {
        S = new QUdpSocket();
        S->bind(port);
        S->connect(S,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(readPendingDiagrams()));
        qDebug() << "Waiting for UDP data from port " << port << " ... \n";
    }

public slots:
    void readPendingDiagrams()
    {
        qDebug() << "Reading thread:" << QThread::currentThreadId();

        while(S->waitForReadyRead())
        {
            QByteArray datagram;
            datagram.resize(S->pendingDatagramSize());
            QHostAddress sender;
            quint16 senderPort;

            S->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(),&sender, &senderPort);
            qDebug() << datagram.size() << " bytes received .... \n";
            qDebug() << " bytes received .... \n";
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QThread *t = new QThread();
    t->start();

    UdpReceiver * net = new UdpReceiver();
    net->moveToThread(t);

    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

I don't have your `UI` code, so I don't know about any issues there. Feel free to post another question if you get stuck there and mention it in a comment and I'll try to help.

Comment: Great Answer, Thank You!
however when I use what you suggested I get this message in console several times : 
"QSocketNotifier: socket notifiers cannot be disabled from another thread "   
Is it something I should worry about (disabling sockets from another thread)? How can I fix this?

Comment: Sorry, I've never actually seen that message. Maybe you should post a new question. If I have some time later I could take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Vahid Nateghi, the init codes and the work codes must run in the same thread. But the constructor of UdpReceiver runs in the main thread against the one readPendingDiagrams runs in, that was the bug. Try this:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>
#include <QUdpSocket>

class UdpReceiver : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QUdpSocket * S;
    int port;
public:
    UdpReceiver(QObject* parent = 0) : QObject(parent)
    {
        qDebug() << ">HERE was the bug! thread:" << QThread::currentThreadId() << "in Construction of UdpReceiver:" << __LINE__ ;
    }

public slots:
    void init_thread(){
        port = 10000;
        qDebug() << ">thread:" << QThread::currentThreadId() << "in init_thread:" << __LINE__ ;
        S = new QUdpSocket();
        S->bind(port);
        S->connect(S,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(readPendingDiagrams()));
        qDebug() << "Waiting for UDP data from port " << port << " ... \n";
    }
    void readPendingDiagrams()
    {
        qDebug() << ">thread:" << QThread::currentThreadId() << "in readPendingDiagrams:" << __LINE__ ;


        while(S->waitForReadyRead())
        {
            QByteArray datagram;
            datagram.resize(S->pendingDatagramSize());
            QHostAddress sender;
            quint16 senderPort;

            S->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(),&sender, &senderPort);
            qDebug() << datagram.size() << " bytes received in thread " << QThread::currentThreadId() << "in readPendingDiagrams:" << __LINE__ ;
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qDebug() << ">Main thread:" << QThread::currentThreadId() << "in main:" << __LINE__ ;
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QThread *t = new QThread();


    UdpReceiver * net = new UdpReceiver();
    net->moveToThread(t);
    net->connect(t,SIGNAL(started()),net,SLOT(init_thread()));
    t->start();

    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```